# How to deal with whitespace in foldernames

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, dir

I am trying to use ffmpeg to process input files with spaces in them.

To check the syntax, I try using Dir in a cmd window and get "file not found".

```
Dir "C:/DigitalSignageManager/LLRA photos/SpinningTop.mp4"
```

I have tried escaping with `\` and `^` and used double and single quotes, but nothing seems to work.

What is the proper syntax to make this work?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using Windows.

Comment: This is a programming question.  I am trying to get ffmpeg to work.  It just so happens it runs on Windows and windows treats the spaces in filenames differently in the cmd window which is where I have to run ffmpeg commands.   So can you answer the question?

Comment: If you're just typing this into the Command Prompt window, it's not programming. It's just using the computer.

Comment: The actual command I am trying to make work is much longer, so I did not post it.  Was trying to simplify it.  ffmpeg -i "C:/DigitalSignageManager/LLRA photos/SpinningTop.mp4" -t 5 -y -vf "movie=\'C:\\\\DigitalSignageManager\\test\\videos\\temp.mov\':seek_point=0, scale=800:600, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [movie]; [in] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, [movie] overlay=80:100 [out]" C:/DigitalSignageManager/test/autoplay/1up_1.mov  fails but if I change the folder name to eliminate the space character, it works just fine.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to escape the space character properly.   If I change the foldername to LLRAphotos with no spaces in it, the ffmpeg command line works.  Adding a space in any foldername causes it to fail.

Comment: Well, that's totally unreadable in the comment section. Please put it into the question so we can read it. But I'm not sure that the rest of the command is relevant, and I don't see how that turns this from using into programming.

Comment: My suspicion is that the folder name doesn't contain an ordinary space character, but some other character that looks like a space.

Comment: But I don't know enough about Windows to know how to tell if that's true or not. But I'll bet you anything the folks at superuser.com would know. That's why this question would be a better fit over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the name. For example: `dir "c:\program files"`

Comment: I did that... as noted in the original post.  It does not work.